# First display promotions in a view

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I use the "[discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount)" module, I created a view to display my products but I can not find how to display the products on sale first in my view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi checkout you view setting 
like this http://prntscr.com/bscbkf
then add filter on it 
http://prntscr.com/bscc0e
now you can see result 
http://prntscr.com/bsccbh
Also explain some more details

Comment: thank you but it does not work because I do not have the same filter you. See the above capture.